# Problem after redirect homepage to /en/

Tags: redirect, seo, plugin-polylang, favicon

My homepage site URL was like this: example.com and example.com/en/ then i want my homepage always have /en/ so i add this code to my function.php but after 1 month my website lost icon when i search in google.

```
function filter_pll_check_canonical_url( $redirect_url, $language ) {
if (is_front_page() && !str_contains($redirect_url,'/en/') && !str_contains($redirect_url,'/vi/') || is_home() && !str_contains($redirect_url,'/en/') && !str_contains($redirect_url,'/vi/')){
    $redirect_url = $redirect_url . 'en/';
}
return $redirect_url;} add_filter( 'pll_check_canonical_url', 'filter_pll_check_canonical_url', 10, 2 );
```

I think because i was redirect my homepage to example.com/en/ so google can’t read my homepage so i was delete this code but it still redirect even i try to remove_filter like this.

```
add_action('init','wpse163434_init');
function wpse163434_init() {
remove_filter('pll_check_canonical_url','filter_pll_check_canonical_url', 99); }

add_action( 'init', 'se334421_remove_plugin_filter' );
function se334421_remove_plugin_filter() {
remove_filter( 'pll_check_canonical_url', 'PLL_Frontend_Translate_Slugs::filter_pll_check_canonical_url', 10 );}
```

So what i need to do to google can read my logo icon or my homepage rollback to example.com no redirect to example.com/en/ anymore.

Comment: Anyone help me pls !!